# Node.js/Express application architecture

Tags: node.js, express

In PHP applications I'm able to create classes hierarchy

```
class UserController  extends Controller {
    public function __constructor(){
        //..
    }
}

class LoggedUserController  extends UserController  {
    protected $_loggedUser;
    public function __constructor(){
        if( empty($_SESSION['user']) ){
            die('Access denied');
        }
        else{
            $this->_loggedUser = $_SESSION['user'];
        }
    }
}

class MessagesController  extends LoggedUserController {
    public function action_get_all(){
        // here I can use $this->_loggedUser and be sure that it is not empty
        //  Something like that:
        $messages = ORM::factory('messages')->where('user_id', '=', $this->_loggedUser->id)->find_all();
    }
}
```

In the same way I can create class AdminUserController and be sure that controller is not available for non-admin users.

But in Node.js I cannot use this trick since constructors of controolers will be called only once, when app is being loaded.

Maybe there is some way to achive this in Node.js?

Comment: try to `NOT` think in PHP

Comment: I'm **LEARNING** not to think in PHP. That's because I've asked this question.

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve something similar in NodeJS using CoffeeScript. CoffeeScript allows you to create classes and other constructs in a cleaner way compared to using plain JavaScript. Although there is a learning curve involved, it probably will be worth it.

As far as the second part of your question goes, you will do the same thing in a different way. You can use request chains in order to achieve this using ExpressJS. For example, consider the following (regular JavaScript approach):

```
app.requiresAdminUser = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.user.role.indexOf('admin') > -1) return next();
    return res.send("Not Authorized", 401);
}

app.get('/site/public/page', function(req, res) {
    res.render('mypage');
});

app.get('/site/admin/secure', app.requiresAdminUser, function(req, res) {
    res.render('mysecurepage');
});
```

I believe the code is self-explanatory. If any part is not clear, do reply with your question.

CoffeeScript can make the above code look cleaner. Also when you are getting into a full blown app, you can put such code inside CoffeeScript classes and instantiate them in your main app file and pass the methods into the routes definition.

Cheers